# grunt-usemin and inline script

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I am starting to use grunt-usemin and want to change the url inside this script where it says

```
baseUrl: "/script/" to 
baseUrl: "/prod/script/"
```

in my layout.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var require = {
      baseUrl: "/script/",
      urlArgs : "cachebust={{version}}",
      deps : ['main']
  };
</script>
```

How do I configure grunt-usemin to do that ?

In my gruntfile.js I have

```
 useminPrepare: {
      html: ['../templates/layout.html']
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['../templates/layout.html']
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Grunt usemin usually cachebust by using a hash on the filename. This way it's also possible to cachebust only selective "builds". lets say you have to compressed files and only one changed, in this scenario you would have only one file to cachebust.